# DB2 sql Max record function

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query in DB2 but is not working, the problem is the max function but I,m not sure how to fix it.

```
SELECT CAR.VI max(CAR.ID),
TU.SOLD 
FROM P.CAR CAR, A.TU TU WHERE CAR.VI = TU.VI

'Table1'                                                              ' VI:     USER:  DATE:      DATE2:     STATUS:   ID'
' 2T1BU4  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 CER       1 '
' 2T1BU4  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 CER       2 '
' 2T1BU3  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 DRA       1 '


' VI:     SOLD:'
' 2T1BU4  Y' 
' 2T1BU3  N'
```

What I want to receive from my query will be something like this:

```
    ' VI:     USER:  DATE:      DATE2:     STATUS:   ID  SOLD'
' 2T1BU4  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 CER       2   Y   '
' 2T1BU3  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 DRA       1   N   '
```

I want to get the VI that have the Max ID

Comment: what is not working?  are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide a lot of details but I am going to take a guess that you want this:

```
SELECT CAR.VI, max(CAR.ID), TU.SOLD 
FROM P.CAR CAR
INNER JOIN A.TU TU 
    ON CAR.VI = TU.VI
GROUP BY CAR.VI, TU.SOLD
```

Or you can use a sub-query:

```
select c1.vi, c1.id, tu.sold
from 
(
    select max(id) id, vi
    from P.CAR
    group by vi
) c1
inner join A.TU TU 
    on c1.VI = TU.VI
```

Comment: Sorry, let me explain more the table could have the same value in the VI field a lot of time, but the ID is diferent it will be incrementing, I want the get the record that have the max ID

Comment: @user1725253 can you post some sample data and the expected result?

Comment: 'Table1'                                                              ' VI:     USER:  DATE:      DATE2:     STATUS:   ID'
' 2T1BU4  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 CER       1 '
' 2T1BU4  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 CER       2 '
' 2T1BU3  DEALER 2012-10-15 2012-10-15 DRA       1 '


' VI:     SOLD:'
' 2T1BU4  Y' 
' 2T1BU3  N'

Answer (score 0):

A variation using a Common Table Expression:

```
with cte (vi, id) as 
(SELECT vi, max(ID)
 FROM P.CAR
 group by vi)
select cte.vi, cte.id, tu.sold
from cte INNER JOIN A.TU TU 
ON cte.VI = TU.VI
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you would like, but it sounds like you would like the record that has the MAX(ID) for each VI.   You need to do something like this:

```
SELECT C1.VI, C1.ID, TU.SOLD FROM P.CAR CAR C1, A.TU TU WHERE C1.VI = TU.VI
WHERE C1.ID = (SELECT MAX(C2.VI) FROM P.CAR C2 WHERE C1.VI = C2.VI)
```